# CSS columns: different render on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-multicolumn-layout

I'm trying to set a 2 column list (on desktop screen) using the `column` CSS property:

```css
.footer .double li {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.footer .double > ul ul {
  padding-left: 40px;
  list-style: circle;
}
.footer .double > ul ul li {
  overflow: visible;
}
.footer .double > ul ul li div {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .footer .double > ul {
    columns: 2;
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    -moz-columns: 2;
  }
  .footer .double > ul ul {
    columns: 1;
    -webkit-columns: 1;
    -moz-columns: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 margin-bottom-20">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/400" alt="" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-6 margin-bottom-20">
        <h3 class="margin-top-0">Mappa del sito</h3>
        <div class="double">
          <!-- subcolumn -->
          <ul class="list-unstyled margin-bottom-0">
            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Tenetur, minus.</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Odio recusandae et officiis hic fuga corrupti. </a>
              <ul>
                <li><div><a href="#">Sequi aut amet nisi qui eveniet</a></div></li>
                <li><div><a href="#">Ipsam, velit exercitationem dolor sit amet</a></div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Illo dolore, amet nam ipsum possimus.</a>
              <ul>
                <li><div><a href="#">Numquam sunt, adipisci necessitatibus.</a></div></li>
                <li><div><a href="#">Facere cum temporibus velit illum amet</a></div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Quisquam libero corrupti repellendus</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Laboriosam corporis, fuga accusantium ipsa</a>
              <ul>
                <li><div><a href="#">Dolore, consectetur atque</a></div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Officia harum animi consequuntur velit</a></li>
          </ul>
          <!-- /subcolumn -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 margin-bottom-20">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/400" alt="" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In Firefox it's all fine: I can see the circle dots in sub lists, and columns are aligned properly on top.

In Chrome, a disaster: sub lists have no circle dots, and columns are not aligned (seems that the second column is mid-aligned instead of top-aligned)

I wrote a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fon4ezjc/1/) showing the problem.

Comment: Note that Chrome has not been 'webkit' in years and you may need to read the notes here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

Answer (score 0):

This diference can be fixed with `"list-style-position"`. 
The browser chrome draw the circle outside of the element  and he is affected when you use `"overflow:hidden"` in your `".footer .double li"`. 
Then using `"list-style-position: outside;"` in your UL you fix it

Comment: sorry, no change with `list-style-position: outside`: https://jsfiddle.net/fon4ezjc/2/